# Why below sequence is diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, numerical-methods

This problem maybe simple for you,but i dont know that why below sequence is diverge?please help me about this:

why $‎\lbrace\mid x_{k}\mid‎\rbrace$ with below definition is diverge?

$x_{k+1}:= x_{k}-(1+x_{k}^2)\arctan x_{k}$ ; $\arctan \mid x_{0}\mid>\dfrac{2\mid x_{0}\mid}{1+x_{0}^2}$

Comment: A title may be useful sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

This series has its only potential steady state on $x^* = 0$. However, not all values of $x_0$ are valid in order to achieve it. In fact, you have to be close enough.

The condition $\arctan |x_0| > \frac{2|x_0|}{1+x_0^2}$ states how far you need to in order to be unable to reach the steady state. Why is this so? In order to have convergence towards your steady state, you need $|x_{k+1}| \leq |x_k|$ for all $k$. Given the functional form of the series, positive values of $x_k$ imply negative values for $x_{k+1}$. So, if $x_0 > 0$, in order to diverge away the steady state we will need $-x_1 > x_0$. So, $-(x_0 - (1+x_0^2)\arctan(x_0) > x_0$, which leads to the expession in the condition to have convergence $\arctan(x_0) > \frac{2x_0}{1+x_0^2}$. The same is true if $x_0$ is negative (and this is why there is absolute values in the condition).